# Cannot connect via ssh to docker container

Tags: docker

I have docker running on a server and I deployed a container, by running:

```sh
docker run -d -p docker_server_ip:3001:22 --name test14 -ti rhel_7_4
```

When running `docker ps` I can see the instance.

Also, I see that Docker server is listening:

```sh
netstat -ntalp | grep 3001
tcp        0      0 docker_server_ip:3001       0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      10362/docker-proxy
```

If I try to ssh to this container I get 'connection refused' (linux iptables is off).

ssh root@docker_server_ip -p 3001 - "ssh: connect to host docker_server_ip  port 3001: Connection refused"

What am I missing?

Comment: Please edit the question with the exact `ssh` command you are using when trying to connect.

Comment: Is the "iptables is off" part of the error message? If yes, I suspect that `iptables` is not working properly on your server, for whatever reason (docker needds iptables).

Comment: in many other systems i saw iptables is off

Comment: What is in the rhel_7_4 image? Are you running a sshd server inside your container? If so, that's a sign of an anti-pattern. And if not, there's nothing to connect to.

Comment: @Miki did you install `openssh-server` on the docker, set `PermitRootLogin yes` in sshd_config, and created `passwd` for root user ?

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to run SSH server inside container, see why and best practices in [this blog post](https://jpetazzo.github.io/2014/06/23/docker-ssh-considered-evil/).

For example, to copy files from Docker, use:

`docker cp {container_name}:{file_path} {target_file_path OR target_dir_ended_with_slash}`

However, if you really need ssh (for example, the container runs on a remote host), make sure the container runs `sshd`, here's how I do it:

- Install sshd and vi: `sudo apt install -y openssh-server vim`
- Set `PermitRootLogin yes` in sshd_config: `sudo vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config`
- Restart `sshd` service: `sudo service ssh restart`
- Add a password to root user: `sudo passwd`

Then you should be able to connect with SSH.